# Как доработать функцию (условие) для отмеченных чекбоксов

Tags: javascript, функции, checkbox, for, inner

```
 {
        checkedModels.forEach(function(elem, index){
          additionalName.innerText +=(index === 0 ? " с " : ", ")+elem.value; 
      
        });
```

При данном условии, при нажатии на чекбоксы выводятся названия в одну строку через запятую. И в начале ставится "с", как дописать чтобы в конце была не запятая, а союз "и"?
Привер: модель П, модель В и модель К.

Comment: `index === checkedModels.length - 1 ? 'и' : ''`

Answer (score 1):

Вот так [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) + [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
additionalName.innerText += ` c ${checkedModels.slice(0, checkedModels.length -1).join(', ')} и ${checkedModels.slice(-1)}`
```

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста ссылку с другим моим вопросом, там наглядно показано и дополнен этот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1272420/265281

Comment: Не пойму как сделать массив из имеющихся чекбоксов, чтобы использовать "slice"